# slicing pandas df based on boolean condition

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

i have two pandas df looking likes this:

```
In [70]: print(r_ret.tail(2))
                 VTI       VOO       VGK       IEV       EWJ
2017-06-22  0.006919  0.028784 -0.269155 -0.707069 -0.223649
2017-06-23  0.089670  0.100813 -0.092122 -0.549094 -0.016048

In [71]: print(rnk.tail(2))
            VTI  VOO  VGK  IEV  EWJ
2017-06-22  2.0  1.0  4.0  5.0  3.0
2017-06-23  2.0  1.0  4.0  5.0  3.0
```

i want to check for two conditions:

```
rnk < 4 and r_ret > 0
```

required output:

```
2017-06-22  VTI  VOO
2017-06-23  VTI  VOO
```

basically want to select the three assets with the highest r_ret whose r_ret is > 0. If there is an efficient way to do this without the rnk df that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using `apply`, which should give significant time savings on dataframes larger than a couple rows:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(((r_ret > 0)
                      & (r_ret.rank(axis=1, ascending=False) < 4)).values
                      * r_ret.columns.values)[:, -3:],
             index=r_ret.index)

Out[264]: 
           0    1    2
2017-06-22    VOO  VTI
2017-06-23    VOO  VTI
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with comparing each row:

```
mask = (rnk < 4) & (r_ret > 0)
df = mask.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.index[x]), axis=1) \
         .rename_axis('date').reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
         date       val
0  2017-06-22  VTI, VOO
1  2017-06-23  VTI, VOO
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `unstack` and `apply` :

```
df[(df > 0) & (df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False) < 4)].unstack().dropna().rename_axis(['symbol', 'date']).reset_index().groupby(['date'])['symbol'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```